# How to sort an arraylist ? If it is numeric or alphabetical?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I used

> arraylist.sort()

method its display sorting of alphabetical string in order but not display number value in sequence.

For Example

I have an arraylist like

```
1
22
21
34
27
68
100
```

and i am sorting this array list using vb.net then its display the output

```
1 
100 
22 
21 
27 
34 
68
```

That means sorting was done but they sorting the array list basis on first character of string but i need in sequence like

```
1
21
22
27
34
68
100
```

and also when i add alphabetical then its also worked.

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP hasn't provided code in question, hence probably the reason for many downvotes. Without code we can't provide a proper solution if we don't have it. Answers that have been provided are assumptions and generic as they do not have your code that is in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `Integer` for the number-strings(then it would sort as expected) you could convert the strings with `Int32.Parse` and use the [`Sort`-overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `IComparer`:

```
arraylist.Sort(Comparer(Of String).Create(Function(s1,s2) Int32.Parse(s1).CompareTo(Int32.Parse(s2))))
```

Of course that works only if all items are really strings that can be converted to `Integer` which raises the question why you haven't used a [`List(Of String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)/`List(Of Int32)` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim list As New ArrayList '- items  as string 
list.Add("1")
list.Add("100")
list.Add("2")
```

and

```
Dim list As New ArrayList '-  items as numerical values 
list.Add(1)
list.Add(100)
list.Add(2)
```

are different.So you should add items to your arraylist accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayList might be containing Strings rather than numbers. change it to numbers and it will be sorted on basis of integer type.

Comment: See answers above